# Квадратный корень из числа, записанного в текстовом файле

Tags: c#, массивы, файлы, split

Необходимо создать программу, которая будет читать число из файла и вычислять корень из этого числа и записывать результат в новый текстовый файл. Проблема заключается в том, что выводится неправильный ответ, подскажите в чем ошибка

```
 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
        {
            string numbers = sr.ReadLine();

            int countOfElements;
            int sqrtOfElement = 0;

            String[] number = numbers.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); 
            countOfElements = numbers.Length; 

            for (int count = 0; count < countOfElements; count++)
            {
                sqrtOfElement += Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(numbers[count])); 
            }

            File.WriteAllText("result.txt", sqrtOfElement.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine(sqrtOfElement);
       
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

Если записать в текстовом файле число 9, то в результате получается 8 вместо 3

Comment: `Convert.ToInt32(Math.Sqrt(numbers[count])); ` что тут происходит? Можете максимально расписать логику этого фрагмента?

Comment: Вся ваша задача сводится к `File.WriteAllText("result.txt", Math.Sqrt(Int32.Parse(File.ReadAllText("file.txt"))).ToString());`